# kettle startup inUbuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, kettle

When I want to start Kettle:

```
$ cd ../kettle/data-integration
$ spoon.sh
```

The following error appears:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/pentaho/ui/xul/XulEventSource
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.ui.xul.XulEventSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 12 more
```

What's wrong? Can anyone help?Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Kettle is currently (5.0) supported using Java 7, please try with JDK or JRE 7
2. That class should be in the pentaho-xul-core jar located in your lib folder, there's a pretty serious problem with your classpath if it can't be found

Please edit spoon.sh to echo the command it's about to run on the last line (add "echo " at the beginning of the last line, exclude the quotes) and post what it comes out with.